# É possível trabalhar com tabelas de atributos de objetos espaciais no Delphi e dbExpress?

Tags: mysql, delphi

Tenho um banco de dados espacial no MySQL onde estão armazenados a geometria e os atributos dos objetos espaciais.

Eu tentei criar um formulário básico, o mais básico possível utilizando *SQLConnection*, *Provider*, *Dataset*, *ClientDataset* e *dbware*, para editar as informações dos objetos.

A diferença foi quando dei o `select *` no *dataset*, pois o Delphi não tem suporte para dados tipo *Geometry* do MySQL, então exclui o campo do tipo *Geometry*.

Aparentemente funciona normalmente porém as edições dos atributos não são feitas mesmo dando o *apply updates*, é necessário fazer alguma coisa a mais no Delphi? Ou o dbExpress não realiza esse processo?

Alguém já tentou trabalhar nessa abordagem que comentei?

Se alguém quiser reproduzir está o SQL com um minimo BD com apenas um objeto espacial.

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Host:                         localhost
-- Server version:               5.6.20-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
-- Server OS:                    Win64
-- HeidiSQL Version:             9.1.0.4867
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;

-- Dumping database structure for gis
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `gis` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `gis`;


-- Dumping structure for table gis.amf
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `amf` (
  `OGR_FID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SHAPE` geometry NOT NULL,
  `id` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hectares` double(19,11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `x` double(19,11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `y` double(19,11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `x2` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `y2` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `OGR_FID` (`OGR_FID`),
  SPATIAL KEY `SHAPE` (`SHAPE`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Dumping data for table gis.amf: 15 rows
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `amf` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `amf` (`OGR_FID`, `SHAPE`, `id`, `name`, `hectares`, `x`, `y`, `x2`, `y2`) VALUES
    (1, _binary 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° 22\' 28.99" W', '7° 2\' 11.06" S'),
    (2, _binary 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, 0, '1', 14.02872517270, 680315.53151200000, 9224249.43888000000, '37° 22\' 3.45" W', '7° 0\' 54.97" S'),
    (3, _binary 0x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° 21\' 46.97" W', '7° 1\' 5.71" S'),
    (4, _binary 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° 21\' 50.23" W', '7° 0\' 56.47" S'),
    (5, _binary 0x010000000103000000010000000D000000588E94CEE1C624418253F36FA9976141B0444721C8C424418253F36FA9976141B0444721C8C424419B563413CC97614120C4DC7CF9C424419B563413CC976141E0F1BC9EE5C824419B563413CC976141185D7DB4E6C824415A7B7A45CB97614140E27DACEAC82441A2A3A462C7976141B877860AF6C82441F0D65A68BA97614130B784A1F8C82441390A7073B7976141307C8084FEC82441DA00F7BAB097614150D86B76FEC8244149CCC5BAB0976141683E9E8556C72441FF934BF1AA976141588E94CEE1C624418253F36FA9976141, 0, '6', 14.02825620420, 680805.13664500000, 9223644.06518000000, '37° 21\' 47.43" W', '7° 1\' 14.62" S'),
    (6, _binary 0x010000000103000000010000000D00000020C4DC7CF9C42441ADD5A28AEF97614120C4DC7CF9C424419B563413CC976141B0444721C8C424419B563413CC976141A891D01764C124419B563413CC976141D871379C18C12441E611F2D5D5976141B84A00A208C12441224EDAE6D7976141B81AC36EBCC02441224EDAE6D797614118D1EE2CCCC0244153932FA4DD976141A866927BCFC024412E37DBD8DE976141D8D4D54E4BC124411B84DCC4E89761417078C58A72C12441ADD5A28AEF97614118BC4BD85BC42441ADD5A28AEF97614120C4DC7CF9C42441ADD5A28AEF976141, 0, '3', 14.02846133560, 680324.71767800000, 9223917.64989000000, '37° 22\' 3.11" W', '7° 1\' 5.77" S'),
    (7, _binary 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° 22\' 19.26" W', '7° 1\' 26.34" S'),
    (8, _binary 0x010000000103000000010000000C000000B0444721C8C424419B563413CC976141B0444721C8C424418253F36FA997614110CA1A3C25C124418253F36FA9976141E8F4718A80C024418253F36FA9976141B0EA853B70C02441453B3CC5B59761416034A9F070C02441390A7073B7976141E8E85C2F72C02441F0D65A68BA9761410022536873C02441B19EA34FBD97614130C0D36E3BC124413DCBD61CBD976141708F3FB564C124419EBED8FECB976141A891D01764C124419B563413CC976141B0444721C8C424419B563413CC976141, 0, '5', 14.02830437450, 680292.02617900000, 9223630.66760000000, '37° 22\' 4.14" W', '7° 1\' 15.11" S'),
    (9, _binary 0x010000000103000000010000000B000000E82F60DFA3C124416914F1C255976141207B949292BE24416914F1C2559761417098F9057CBE24417CC5B9E561976141E0FB11D320BE2441C75A66E26897614148A92CCAF8BD2441B7F498F36B9761419825BE7BB2BD24417A00726D6F976141980109F96ABD2441E9CE88F672976141E05DB08364BD2441DDFA37C37B97614110CA1A3C25C12441DDFA37C37B976141E82F60DFA3C12441DDFA37C37B976141E82F60DFA3C124416914F1C255976141, 0, '9', 14.02819636160, 679911.46004000000, 9222992.94250000000, '37° 22\' 16.47" W', '7° 1\' 35.92" S'),
    (10, _binary 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° 22\' 4.19" W', '7° 1\' 24.92" S'),
    (11, _binary 0x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° 22\' 10.90" W', '7° 1\' 46.14" S'),
    (12, _binary 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° 22\' 1.20" W', '7° 1\' 36.56" S'),
    (13, _binary 0x010000000103000000010000000B00000090F06BADAEC42441B9E82C952D97614190F06BADAEC424416D1B30FBF39661418015C9CE8CC424414D1E147DF396614168B93ECEF2C32441E20542CF18976141B0B0841AEEBF244141AD74A414976141A0971546E2BF24411AC9B0081A97614188C99BFDC1BF244171E14BBF289761412031CA1ABBBF2441FBE056692B97614130DA2A7EB5BF2441B9E82C952D976141E030C396E0C22441B9E82C952D97614190F06BADAEC42441B9E82C952D976141, 0, '13', 12.89274416940, 680250.52935000000, 9222394.36923000000, '37° 22\' 5.35" W', '7° 1\' 55.36" S'),
    (14, _binary 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° 21\' 51.27" W', '7° 1\' 58.93" S'),
    (15, _binary 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° 21\' 56.50" W', '7° 1\' 46.56" S');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `amf` ENABLE KEYS */;


-- Dumping structure for table gis.geometry_columns
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `geometry_columns` (
  `F_TABLE_CATALOG` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `F_TABLE_SCHEMA` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `F_TABLE_NAME` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `F_GEOMETRY_COLUMN` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `COORD_DIMENSION` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SRID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TYPE` varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Dumping data for table gis.geometry_columns: ~0 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `geometry_columns` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `geometry_columns` (`F_TABLE_CATALOG`, `F_TABLE_SCHEMA`, `F_TABLE_NAME`, `F_GEOMETRY_COLUMN`, `COORD_DIMENSION`, `SRID`, `TYPE`) VALUES
    (NULL, NULL, 'amf', 'SHAPE', 2, 1, 'POLYGON');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `geometry_columns` ENABLE KEYS */;


-- Dumping structure for table gis.spatial_ref_sys
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `spatial_ref_sys` (
  `SRID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AUTH_NAME` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUTH_SRID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SRTEXT` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Dumping data for table gis.spatial_ref_sys: ~0 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `spatial_ref_sys` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `spatial_ref_sys` (`SRID`, `AUTH_NAME`, `AUTH_SRID`, `SRTEXT`) VALUES
    (1, NULL, NULL, 'PROJCS["SIRGAS_2000_UTM_Zone_24S",GEOGCS["GCS_SIRGAS_2000",DATUM["Sistema_de_Referencia_Geocentrico_para_las_AmericaS_2000",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",10000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-39.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `spatial_ref_sys` ENABLE KEYS */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

Comment: @QMechanic73 é justamente o tipo de dado GEOMETRY que o Delphi não consegue entender. Dá uma olhada nesse [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28136489/editing-attributes-of-spatial-data-in-delphi-mysql-dbexpress)

Comment: Este é o tipo [link](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcsde/9.1/general_topics/wkb_representation.htm), tenho que encontrar uma forma de ler esse tipo de arquivo.

Comment: @QMechanic73 cara consegui finalmente, praticamente sem querer, no provider eu coloquei em updatemode upwherekeyonly, e puff deu o apply updates, porém não sei explicar e nem sei o porque.

Comment: @QMechanic73 então dei uma estudada e cheguei uma conclusão, como tinha uma tabela de objetos espaciais o qual não podia trazer o campo do tipo GEOMETRY, eu fazia o select em todos os campos menos esse, ou seja nos atributos, quando ia dar o update como estava no `upWhereAll` ele incluia o campo tipo GEOMETRY e no reconcile error dava aquele erro de registro modificado por outro usuário. Deixando `upWhereKeyOnly` ele bota os campos modificados na query e o id, ai não da problema.

Comment: @QMechanic73 então desculpa por ter dito que era o problema do decimal, e acabei fazendo você dar a resposta abaixo.

Comment: @QMechanic73 não gosto de responder as minhas próprias  perguntas, delete sua resposta e coloque a solução que eu aceito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Atualização**: A solução encontrada para contornar esse problema, segundo o autor foi fazer um `SELECT` em todos os campos menos o campo do tipo *Geometry*, e alterar o [modo de atualização](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Data.DB.TProviderFlag) de `upWhereAll` para `upWhereKeyOnly`.

Ao colocar os campos modificados na *query* e o *ID* a atualização será baseada em colunas chaves especificas. Assim não sendo necessário o código abaixo.

---

Como citado por você, o problema acontece quando esses dados são importados para o seu programa, que ao invés de vir no formato `xx.xxxx` retorna `xx,xxx` e por causa disto o `ApplyUpdates` não funciona.

Você pode tentar fazer um *replace* trocando `,` por `.` assim:

```
function replaceComma(const str : string ): string;
begin
Result := StringReplace(str, ',', '.', [rfReplaceAll]);
end;
```

Esse *replace* pode ser chamado antes de salvar os dados, poderá usa-lo no evento [`BeforePost`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.BeforePost) do `DataSet`.

Comment: @user21051 você pode fazer um for nos Fields do dataset no beforePost como sugerido pelo QMechanic73, se forem vários fields ou um a um mesmo se forem poucos